# Any insights on why my type is not being properly used in the generic function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Code Example in ReactJS:

The record type being rendered in the `render` function can vary depending upon the application. This seemed like the perfect use case for a generic.  Any ideas why this doesn't work as I expected?

```
type Column = {
  title?: string;
  key: string;
  className?: string;
  sort?: boolean;
  isVisible?: boolean;
  render?: <Type>(record: Type) => ReactNode;
};

type Customer = {
  customerAddress: { street1: string };
};

const columns: Column[] = [
  {
    title: "Street Address",
    key: "customerAddress.street1",
    sort: true,
    filter: {
      type: "string",
    },
    render: function <Customer>(record: Customer) {
      return record?.customerAddress?.street1;
    },
  },
];
```

I get the following error:

```
any
Property 'customerAddress' does not exist on type 'NonNullable<Customer>'.ts(2339)
```

I was expecting `customerAddress` to exist in the definition.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic function needs to be able to handle any type argument passed in by the caller ([see this video for an explanation](https://youtu.be/kYxhAsIW3NU)

What you really want is to make the `Column` type generic:

```
type Column<Type> = {
  title?: string;
  key: string;
  className?: string;
  sort?: boolean;
  isVisible?: boolean;
  render?: (record: Type) => ReactNode;
};

type Customer = {
  customerAddress: { street1: string };
};

const columns: Column<Customer >[] = [
  {
    title: "Street Address",
    key: "customerAddress.street1",
    sort: true,
    render: function (record: Customer) {
      return record?.customerAddress?.street1;
    },
  },
];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwEoFMCGBjGA5CATFOAXwDMoIQ4ByKdLKgWAChnmYBPMQgYQgBsAriAB2AHgAqnFAD44AXkTM4cGMBh8UAfgBccAM4wowYQHMA3ErgBrFO10Gjpi02UY+aPXuxoQW+4eNzSz1oGB04ACMIfnRhZ2VgPQA1ROAIjXComLQ4y1phAihwgApaDGg8XUkuAEp5WVRMHHwUZyJnNik4bgEDChQoeUUXOAxemH6oAEE8PFpPXQR9QxQUGABGf0cTYjaOpnLhA1H+ISPdXkERUR6+30HpAG0AXSHHywRLZVV1FF0AIgAyis1nAZnMUJ5-gAaL7WWwAsZ3Abg+Z6AB0DlWGxhcJCsF0hgEKFhI2U+UKuhIAmEWGAEGEcFKKHKUEq3XGkzqnzJyjgtBgAigjLKFU06KRE3uqMhenFWLW63ifKIpOUquYzzMQA)